# Update a table's foreign key that is duplicate from a specific tuple in other table with the right one

Tags: sql, postgresql

Database :

**Car table**

| id | serialnumber | plate | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 11111 |  |
| 2 | AA | 11111 | Ford |
| 3 | BB | 22222 | Tesla |
| 4 | BB | 22222 |  |

**User table**

| id | car_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 linked to a duplicate without name) |
| 2 | 1 linked to a duplicate without name) |
| 3 | 3 |

**Expected user table after query**

| id | car_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 (now linked to duplicate with name) |
| 2 | 2 (now linked to duplicate with name) |
| 3 | 3 (linked to a duplicate but has name so doesn't change) |

The tuple (`serialnumber, plate`) has duplicates, and amongst those duplicates, one has a name, one doesn't.
Assume that duplicates are at a maximum of 2.
One user can only be affected to one car

I'm trying to reaffect all users that are linked to **a duplicated car with no name**(identified by **serialnumber, plate**) to the same car **WITH** a name.

My query :

```sql
    UPDATE user u
    SET car_id = c.id
    FROM car c
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM (SELECT *,
                              count(*)
                              OVER
                                  (PARTITION BY
                                  serialnumber,
                                  plate
                                  ) AS count
                       FROM car) c2
                 WHERE c2.count > 1
                   AND c2.serialnumber = c.serialnumber
                   AND c2.plate = c.plate)
    AND c.name <> '';
```

I had only one duplicate and tested with a `WHERE c.id=...` clause and it worked, rerunning it after removing clause affected 300+ rows and messed up my data, so obviously something went wrong (unless reaffecting same value to a column counts?), any idea ?

**Thanks for your help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
update user
set car_id = c2.id
from user u
inner join car c on u.car_id = c.id 
inner join car c2 on c.serialnumber = c2.serialnumber and c.plate = c2.plate
where c.name = '' and c2.name <> ''
```